# How to edit the physicsbody of SKNode in SpriteKit Editor of Xcode

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I am learning SpriteKit, looking the demo application, adventure, I find the SKNode wall have physicsbody, it seems the physicsbody is setup in the SKS file because I searched all the code and find nothing about wall physicsbody setting.
all about the physicsbody of wall in code is here:

```
wallNode.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
wallNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue
```

So I think the way to setup physicsBody of the SKNode is in the SKS file, but in SpriteKit editor, I can't change anyting about the physics body.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is in the SpriteKit scene editor for the sks file.  Select the node and in the SKNode inspector towards the bottom there is a "Physics Definition" drop down.  I had a hard time finding it also.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't find the Physics Definition in the bottom. My Xcode version is 6.3.1, can you give me your version?

Comment: Yes Xcode 6.3.  Make sure you have the sks file open with a sprite selected in the scene editor.  Also activate View-->Utilities-->Show SkNode Inspector.

Comment: Thanks again. I know what your meaning, and the issure is when I choose a node in the scene editor rather than sprite, the "Physics Definition" do not appear in the Inspector, it seems node in the scene can't assign with  a physics body. But in the example given by Apple, they do add the physics body to the node named wall, and they do this outside the code, so I wondering how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/

> To add physics to a node, create and configure an SKPhysicsBody object and then assign it to the physicsBody property of the SKNode object. A physics body must be associated with a node object before you apply forces or impulses to it.

You should modify your wall physicsBody depending on what you want.
For example:

// Physics body size

```
bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/2)
```

// Not dynamic

```
bird.physicsBody.dynamic = false
```

// Can not rotate

```
bird.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
```

Comment: But I looking all code in the example, there is no create physicsBody. May be it is being created in SKS file, but how?

Comment: You create your node physics body by giving it size.
bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/2)

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do in code, but in apple's example, the game adventure do this in sks file, which I want to figure out how they do this excellent things.

Answer (score 0):

To change physics properties in the Editor, you need to follow this way:

1. Select you node
2. Open the "Utilities" panel (the right panel in Xcode)
3. Open "Attributes Inspector" in it (3rd option)
4. Scroll down to "Physics Definition" section
5. Change necessary property

Screenshot (how to find "Physics Definition" section):
[image: Screenshot]